# Insert order data from csv programatically in Magento 2.2

Tags: database, magento2.2, php-7

I have 2 different CSV files 1st has orders and 2nd have order details. I am trying to insert data into magento2 DB using Magento Models. so that my data will insert into all different tables and will also show on the Admin side.

Right now I have inserted data in DB but the data is just inserted into **sales_order** table, all the other tables related to orders are empty, that's why order's data is not showing on the Admin side.

**Need some serious help**

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

Comment: Specify the code which you have try? and also does it show any error on screen?

Comment: no it's working fine, and inserting the orders data in Sales_order table, but Magento uses EAV system, that's why I have to insert data according to that method, which I don't know.